# Game where input field value and randomised number match to increase or decrease score

Tags: javascript, html

The project I am currently working on involves a game that includes two buttons ("start game" and "stop game"), a chosen number (prompt box where the user can enter an integer between 0 and 9), the users score (starting off at zero) and three randomised numbers in the range from 0 to 9.

I have completed and worked out every solution to the game except the randomised numbers matching with the user input field. For example, if the user was to select "6" as their desired number, they would have the opportunity to click every time between the three zones of randomised numbers until they see a "6". Every time the "6" is clicked, the user gains a point and every time a number other than "6" is clicked, the user's total points gets deducted. Score starts at zero and can have negative score.

Below is the code for my randomised numbers and input field prompt box:

Is there any way I could emulate this design with scoring essentially matching the input value with their respective numbers?

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated... sorry for the long question!

Cheers.

```
<script>

var txt;

function chooseNum() 
{
var txt;
var person = prompt("Choose an integer between 0 and 9:");
if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
} else {
    txt = person;
}
document.getElementById("chosen").innerHTML = txt;
}

function randomNumber()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* 9 + 1);
$('#number1').html(rand);

}
</script>

<script>

var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber1();},1000);

function randomNumber1()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML = rand;

}

</script>

<script>

var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber2();},1000);

function randomNumber2()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML = rand;

}

</script>

<script>

var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber3();},1000);

function randomNumber3()
{
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*9);

document.getElementById("number3").innerHTML = rand;

}

</script>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and put relevant code in the correct panels - we need to see a [mcve]. Right now your question is very unclear so add expected and actual output

Comment: You can only have one `var id` - I suggest you have an array of ids. Also it seems you have jQuery running, so why not use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. Here is a start using an IIFE and the jQuery you seem to have available.

```js
var txt;

function chooseNum() {
  var person = prompt("Choose an integer between 0 and 9:");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt."
  } else {
    txt = person;
    runIt();
  }
  $("#chosen").html(txt)
}

function runIt() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    (function(i) {
      var interval = setInterval(function() {
          var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
          $('#number' + i).html(rand);
        },
        1000);
    })(i);
  }
}
$(function(){
  chooseNum()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="chosen"></span> -
<span id="number1"></span><span id="number2"></span><span id="number3"></span>
```